# How to change grid column value on DataBound event

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following Grid,

```
<div class="kotgrid">
</div>
```

And I bound the data as following. Here I want to change `timedelay` column value on DataBound event,

```
$(".kotgrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource, 
    dataBound: function (e) {
        var grid = this;
        grid.tbody.find('>tr').each(function () {
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
            var d = new Date();
            var currentTime = parseTime(dataItem.servertime);
            var currenTime = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
            var meanTime = diff(orderTime2, currenTime2)
            //I want to set this meanTime in timedelay coloumn. How can I achieve this?
        })
    },
    filterable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    columns: [
                   { hidden: true, field: "orderitemid" },
                   { field: "tableid", title: "Table No" },
                   { field: "itemname", title: "Items" },
                   { field: "quantity", title: "Quantity" },
                   { field: "modifier", title: "Modifier" },
                   { hidden: true, field: "orderedtime", title: "Time Delay" },
                   { field: "timedelay", title: "Time Delay" },
                   { hidden: true, field: "alert" },
                   { hidden: true, field: "category", groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #" },
                   { command: { text: "Pickup", click: showDetails} }
             ],
    mobile: "phone",
    editable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    height: "600px"
});
```

I don't know how to achieve it. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the `<tr>` elements, unless you only want to do it for the current page. You can just iterate over grid.dataSource.data().
So you could do something like:

```
var data = this.dataSource.data();
$(data).each(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var currentTime = parseTime(this.servertime);
    var currenTime = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    var meanTime = diff(orderTime2, currenTime2)
    // set on dataItem
    this.set("timedelay", meanTime);
});
```

Regardless of how you get access to the `dataItem`, you can set any property using the [set](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject#methods-set) method (the data source contains Model items which inherit from ObservableObject).

Comment: Chrome says **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'set'** friend.

Comment: @Gunaseelan are you iterating over `dataSource.data()` like I do? If you're iterating over the `tr` elements, then you need to get the dataItem like you did in your question (`grid.dataItem(this);`).

Comment: @Gunaseelan OK, I just noticed that I had a copy/paste error - I replaced dataItem in my code with "this" in line 4. Something else I noticed: what is dataItem.servertime? I don't see that column in your column definitions.

Comment: Super friend, Thank you so much, Woks like awesome!! Thanks once again friend, I have wasted near 4 hours for this. You saved my remaining time.

Comment: Can you say me how to dispaly timer in that column friend, In detail I want to update the meanTime an every second like stopWatch.

Comment: use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and update it once a second from there in the same way

Comment: In the last line, it must be `this.timedelay = meanTime;`